# Using Mathematica to run an external bash script

Tags: parallelization, linux, external-calls

This seems like a straightforward problem, but I am having trouble. I have a bash script that runs a parallel process (OpenFoam). I would like to call this script from a Mathematica Module.

Processes like Run, RunProcess, RunThrough, WriteLine, ect... all seem to run within a Mathematica kernel and this is preventing OpenFoam from running on multiple cores.

Current best guess:  `WriteLine[StartProcess[$SystemShell],"path/to/script"];` to run the script on the system shell.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: I can't replicate this behaviour - doing `RunProcess[{"make", "-j24"}, 
 ProcessDirectory -> "~/workspace/emacs/emacs"]` uses all 24 of my cores. Can you provide some more detail, or perhaps a minimum working example?

Comment: Run, RunProcess and the like do *not* run within the Mathematica kernel, they start extra processes. What might be different is the settings of some environment variables when these processes are started from within the Mathematica kernel. You would need to check how OpenFoam parallelism is controlled. There might be extra arguments you have to give like the `-j24` in Carls example or some environment variables you have to set. I think you might get more specific answers in a QA page about OpenFoam...

Comment: Thanks for your responses. Carl I did try your suggestion (unfortunately I had no luck). OpenFoam starts and runs only using one core.

Comment: Albert, thanks for elaborating. I will see if I can get it working. And post the solution here if I find one.